# C2470 error Visual Studio 2012 and Qt 4.8.6

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, msvc12

I'm making small lib for my R&D needs. For that needs I use Qt 4.8.6 and Visual Stuido 2012.

Here's my `.pro` file

```
TEMPLATE    = lib
TARGET      = mylib
CONFIG      += dll

HEADERS = mymath.h

SOURCES = mymath.cpp \

INCLUDEPATH +=  ../include \

DEFINES += MYMATHIMPL
```

Here's `.h` file with my class

```
#ifndef MY_MATH_H
#define MY_MATH_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>


#if defined(MYMATHIMPL)
# define MYMATHAPI Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
# define MYMATHAPI Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

typedef struct
{
  double * b;
  double * c;
  double * d;
  double * _m;
} akima_state_t;

class MYMATHAPI AkimaInterpolator
{
public:
    AkimaInterpolator(double * _x_values, double * _y_values, size_t size);
    AkimaInterpolator(double *d, double *c, double* b, double *_x_values, double* _y_values, size_t _size);
    ~AkimaInterpolator();
    double evaluateAtX(double x);
    static int searchIndex(const double sortedArray[], double toFind, int len);
};
```

`.cpp` file contains all declared method with implementation as well.

But when I'm trying to build this library I've got error:

> mymath.h(31): error C2470: AkimaInterpolator:: looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body.

I've checked comiler flags and it seems that `MYMATHIMPL` is set.

```
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DACPMATHIMPL -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__ST
    DC_FORMAT_MACROS -DSPM_VERSION_INFO -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -D
    QT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include\QtCore" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include\QtGui" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include" -I"..\include" -I"..\..\common\include" -I"-I"..\..\common\include" -I"..\
    ..\common\include" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\include\ActiveQt" -I"..\..\..\temp\acp_v2\debug" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.6\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fo..\..\..\temp\acp_v2\debug\ @C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC62D.tmp
```

What am I doing wrong? Why block:

```
#if defined(MYMATHIMPL)
    # define MYMATHAPI Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
    # define MYMATHAPI Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Because Q_DECL_EXPORT is not defined?

Comment: @n.m. it looks like so, but I can't get why `Q_DECL_EXPORT` is not defined. It should be defined because of the last metioned block

Comment: @tema: No, that defines `MYMATHAPI`, not either of the `Q_DECL` macros.

Comment: you title says VS2015 but your question text mentions VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included any QT headers that might define `Q_DECL_EXPORT` or `Q_DECL_IMPORT`, nor are they defined by the command line. So your use of `MYMATHAPI` is expanded to `Q_DECL_EXPORT`, rather than whatever that's supposed to expand to.

I think they are defined in `<QtGlobal>`.

Comment: Thank you, I've missed `QT += core` in `.pro` file. Adding `#include <QtCore>` to mymath.h and editing `.pro` file solved this porblem. I'll check answer as right as soon as it will be possible.